# Can I add an Outlook Attachment from a PictureBox image?

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, attachment

I have an image in my VB.NET Picture box. I would like to attach it to the email message I'm sending through Outlook without having to save it to the drive anywhere. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Here's what I have so far (taken from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/html/tr/sidebars/5850937-1.html)):

```
Public Class email
    Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
    Dim appNameSpace As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace
    Dim memo As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outbox As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Public Sub New(ByVal attachment)
        Try
            app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
            appNameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            appNameSpace.Logon(Nothing, Nothing, False, False)

            memo = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            memo.To = "notmy@realemailaddress.com"
            memo.Subject = "Testing"
            memo.Body = "Hello there"
            memo.Attachments.Add(attachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue)
            memo.Send()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

When I comment out the attachment line it works perfectly fine, otherwise it throws a COMError. I haven't been able to find any real good information about attaching an email that way, or if it's even possible. If I can't do it this way I plan on just saving the file to some random(ish) name in C:\TEMP\, but it would be nicer if I didn't have to worry about that.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your options: [Attachment Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olattachmenttype.aspx)

The source information here can help also:[Attachment Add Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add.aspx)